# Ist die Konstruktion "xy gibt es keine" grammatikalisch korrekt?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality, grammar-identification

In Zeitungsartikeln trifft man oft auf die Formulierung

> Hinweise auf ein Delikt gibt es keine.

statt "Hinweise auf ein Delikt gibt es nicht" oder "Es gibt keine Hinweise auf ein Delikt".

Mich interessiert die Konstruktion "xy gibt es keine/wenige/viele" usw.

1. Ist sie überhaupt grammatikalisch korrekt?
2. Was geschieht in diesem Satz mit dem Akkusativ-Objekt? Hat der Satz zwei Akkusativ-Objekte?
3. Funktioniert diese Konstruktion nur mit Mengenangaben (Zahlwörtern und Indefinitpronomen) oder gibt es weitere Beispiele?

Comment: Bonusfrage: Ist *Hinweise* Akkusativ oder Genitiv?

Comment: Alter DDR-Witz: "Gibt's hier keine Hosen?" - "Nein, hier gibt's keine Mäntel. Keine Hosen gibt's im ersten Stock"

Comment: @CarstenS: Wen oder was gibt es nicht? "Hinweise (auf ein Delikt)". Wie könnte das Genitiv sein? Wessen ...?

Comment: @userunknown, hört sich „der Hinweise gibt es keine“ für dich völlig absurd an?

Comment: Hmm... "Wovon gibt es keine?" -- "Hinweise auf ein Delikt."

Comment: Wessen gibt es keine? Ich würde das nicht unbedingt sagen, aber das heißt nicht, dass es falsch wäre.

Comment: @CarstenS: Jetzt, wo Du so fragst: Doch. Hört sich richtig an. Der Hinweise auf ein Delikt gibt es keine. Nicht "Wen gibt es keine?" sondern "Was gibt es nicht?" Tückisch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interessanter Fall. Als deutschsprachig Aufgewachsener finde ich die Konstruktion völlig transparent und normal. Berufsgeschädigt als Computerlinguist schlage ich natürlich die Hände über dem Kopf zusammen, weil sie so weit vom Modellfall abweicht (und damit maschinell schlecht verarbeitbar ist).

1. Korrekt: Ja, in dem Sinne, dass sie gut verstanden wird. Ob ein offizielles Regelwerk nun zufällig daran gedacht hat, dass Menschen so sprechen und die Formulierung damit ausdrücklich sanktioniert oder nicht, finde ich weniger wichtig.
2. M.E. ist das Akkusativobjekt ganz normal eine Determiner-Phrase "keine Hinweise", nur dass sie eben durch die Topikalisierung des Nomens ins Vorfeld maximal weit auseinandergerissen wurde. Das ist ziemlich einmalig und für den Theoretiker provozierend, denn genau so verhalten sich  zusammenhängende Phrasen eigentlich nicht.
3. Ich könnte mir zumindest vorstellen, daß verwandte Determiner dasselbe Schicksal erleiden: "*Werkzeug* musste ich *mein eigenes* mitbringen." Ich kann aber nicht beschwören, ob ich das wirklich je gehört habe oder ob mein Sprachgefühl jetzt schon vom vielen Nachdenken über Dein Beispiel ruiniert ist.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Das tönt für mich plausibel: Ein Teil des Akkusativobjekts wird nach vorne gezogen.

Comment: Als Computerlinguist kennst du vermutlich diese Seite: https://pub.cl.uzh.ch/demo/parzu/ Dieser Perser zerlegt den Satz wie folgt: [*Hinweise auf ein Delikt*] = Dativobjekt eines Verbs mit einer Dativ-Valenz, [*gibt*] = Finites Vollverb, [*es*] = Subjekt des finiten Verbs, [*keine*] = Akkusativobjekt (zweites Komplement eines transitiven Verbs). Das Dativ-Objekt wird weiter zerlegt: [*Hinweise*] = männliches Nomen im Dativ, [*auf ein Delikt*] = Präpositionalphrase mit [*auf*] = Präposition, [*ein Delikt*] = Komplement einer Präposition ...

Comment: ... besehend aus: [*Delikt*] = sächliches Nomen im Akkusativ, [*ein*] = Determiner eines Nomen, hier ein sächlicher unbestimmter Artikel im Akkusativ. Ich finde, die Maschine, die diesen Satz verarbeitet hat, hat ihre Sache recht gut gemacht.

Answer (score 2):

Ich lese gerade einen Aufsatz zur Transformationsgrammatik, demzufolge diskontinuierliche Phrasen relativ normal sind. Euer Beispiel kommt auch vor:

> Was man in der GG Derivation nennt, bezieht sich, vereinfacht gesagt, auf den Umstand, dass sich Elemente oftmals nicht in ihrer Basisposition befinden – also dort, wo sie zunächst in die Phrasenstruktur eingebracht werden. Als direkte Evidenz dafür kann man diskontinuierliche Konstituenten betrachten, die ja auf irgendeine Weise getrennt worden sein müssen. In den folgenden Beispielen ist die Basisposition der bewegten Teilkonstituenten in Form durchgestrichener Kopien angezeigt:
>
> (21) a. [Bücher über Linguistik [habe [ich [DP keine <strike>Bücher über Linguistik die mich gefesselt hätten</strike>] gelesen] ] [die mich gefesselt hätten] ]
>
> b. Diese Studenten haben [DP alle <strike>diese Studenten</strike>] ihre Hausaufgaben ] gemacht ]
>
> c. Kam der Zug in Buxtehude an<strike>kam</strike>? [VP [DP (Partikelzurücklassung bei V+FIN -Bewegung)

Ich interpretiere das dahingehend, dass die Sätze in a. und b. nicht problematischer sind als jeder andere Satz mit trennbarem Verb. Ist doch schön, oder? :-)

Öhl, Peter. 2015. Satz – aus Sicht der Generativen Grammatik. In Christa Dürscheid & Jan Georg Schneider (Hrsg.), *Handbuch Satz, Äußerung, Schema* (Handbücher Sprachwissen 4). Berlin: De Gruyter Mouton. Seite 216.

Comment: Man nennt das offenbar auch _Aufspaltung der Nominalphrase_ oder _Quantorenfloating_ und die entsprechende Satzstellung _Distanzstellung_. Eine Reihe von Beispielen gibts hier: http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/sysgram.ansicht?v_typ=v&v_id=1103&v_wort=Aufspaltung